# What is the fate of VODKA Indexing, is it dead?

Tags: postgresql, index

I see numerous mentions online of [Vodka indexing with regard to PostgreSQL](http://www.pgcon.org/2014/schedule/events/696.en.html).

On the Wiki it's defined as,

> (Korotkov) Vodka maintains two index files, one for keys and one for heap item pointers (postings). Each index file can be, in effect, managed by a different access method. This is a generalization of GIN, which uses btree (albeit its own btree code, not src/backend/access/nbtree) for both keys and postings. The keys index file has item pointers that refer to the postings index file. When the postings file's access method needs to move an index item, it must arrange to update any item pointer in the keys file. To that end, proposing a new "amupdateiptr" access method function. Calls to that function, when necessary, will arrive right after an amgettuple call.

Aside from that, you can see this [post on the list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAF4Au4xZDFhhxcBJkKhw2mv768Cpdr1U3WdC3hxLWOFYdRR5JQ%40mail.gmail.com)

> We are on the way to postgres-centric company and we'll continue our
>   development in that company. We certainly don't need funding for the VODKA, our national product :)  I thought about crowd-funding, but didn't find any good cases for products similar to postgres. So, we decided to go
>   traditional way - built our own company and get money from industry. In
>   short perspective we delay our development, since many-many other
>   non-developers business, but in long perspective we'll have more russian
>   contributors for the postgres project.  Postgres in Russia was popular
>   database, but now it gets much more interests from business and goverment,
>   so I'm quite optimistic.

What ever happened to this and is it dead or did it get merged into something else?

Comment: I don't know where they're going with VODKA, but I attended a talk in february about RUM...  https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgresproee/9.6/rum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question when I last saw Alexander (who is Vodka's developper).
To him, Vodka was more a Proof of Concept than an actual thing suitable for production. He needs to rewrite it all to achieve production-ready code.

But, he has a lot of things to do and so the project is frozen for now.

Cheers,

Arkena

Comment: Cool cool he's a bad ass, hope him and the Russian team keep up the good work.